# Get value for associated cell onchange

Tags: javascript, json, drop-down-menu, hta

I have an .hta with a set of drop down boxes that are created dynamically inside of a table. The table generates from a json file. The table looks like (there is obviously more to the table but this gives you an idea):

```
output +=
"<td style='display:none' name='expensive' style='background-color:#EDEDED'><center><input id='expensive_box' type='checkbox'></center></td>" + 
"<td style='display:none' name='cheap'><center><input id='cheap_box' type='checkbox'></center></td>" + 
"<td style='display:none' id='Spdropsyst' name='SPdropsyst'><select class='jumpmenu' name='SpRating' id='SpRating' onchange='writeRate()'><option id='blank' selected='selected'>...</option><option id='accepted' value=''>SP Accepted</option><option id='declined' value=''>SP Declined</option></select></td>";
output += 
"<td id='biz_name'>" + results[i]["Business Name"] + "</td>" +
"<td style='display:none' name='addressCol'>" + results[i]["Address"] + "</td>" + 
"<td><center>" + results[i]["City"] + "</center></td>" + 
"<td><center>" + results[i]["StateListing"] + "</center></td>";
```

Each row is then written with

document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;

Each row is generated with its own dropdown. The onchange function is:

```
function writeRate()
{

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var write_id = "file to write to here";
alert('The information has been forwarded to the OON Map Team, Thank you!');
var s = fso.OpenTextFile(write_id, 8, true);
alert(write_id);

s.WriteLine(" ");
if (document.getElementById('cheap_box').checked){
s.WriteLine('cheap');
}

if (document.getElementById('expensive_box').checked){
s.WriteLine('expensive');
}
s.Close();
}
```

Now what I am looking for is when the box on line x is changed, I want it to grab the business name of the same row x to be written out to a file. So if someone changes drop x, it will write out business x, and if someone changes drop y, then it will write out business y.

I am passing the business names into an array as I generate the table. So I do have:

```
spArray.push(results[i]["Business Name"];
```

and am able to call any of the names, but cannot associate a name with a box. How would I get this done in the simplest way?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with "Each row is then written with `.innerHTML = output`. `innerHTML` of any table element is read-only (except  `td`) in IE.

Comment: Not sure what your looking for, but pretty much its just writing the information to the div marked placeholder. If you need more of the code I can do that, just need to let me know what parts you need.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out by instead taking the array spArray and using it to populate a drop down list instead. So instead of having a dynamically created set of drop downs I have one drop down, which I can then grab the selected value from the drop down easily. Problem solved to my happiness.